# Line number order is broken

Tags: line-numbers, spacevim

I recently installed Neovim and SpaceVim. My line number order is broken:

[image: Broken line numbers]

This occurs when working on any file, with both Vim and Neovim.

How do I solve this? I'm a newbie to Vim and don't know how to go about troubleshooting it.

Comment: Looks like I have `relativenumber` turned on. I haven't specified this in any configuration files. I'm figuring out the issue ATM.

Comment: `:set norelativenumber`, see also `:h number_relativenumber`

Comment: `relativenumber` comes in handy if you’re going to be jumping around with commands like `7k`, `18j`, etc. I’m much more likely to jump around to absolute numbers, but that seems to be why people like it, if you were curious why this is a thing.

Comment: To see where it was set, you can use `:verbose set relativenumber`

Comment: Thanks all. I ended up just using Neovim anyway instead of SpaceVim, which fixed the issue. SpaceVim (or one of its plugins) must have been setting `relativenumber` somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SpaceVim, we use `g:spacevim_relativenumber` to config relativenumber. if by default it is 1, if you want to disable this feature. just add
`let g:spacevim_relativenumber = 0` to your custom config. the config can be opened via `SPC f v d`.

**why we make this option enabled by default?**

because relativenumber is very useful for line move, you can use `7j` to move down 7 line, and you can see the `7` before moving.

Answer (score 3):

Custom config didn't work for me. So I did this:

```
$ find ~/.SpaceVim/ -type f | xargs grep spacevim_relativenumber
```

And found the line in `.SpaceVim//autoload/SpaceVim.vim`:

```
let g:spacevim_relativenumber          = 1
```

Then I changed this setting to `0`. It looks like little bit more generic way that can also be applied to other settings.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this helped me to fix it.